# using sqlite3 with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 with Ruby and ActiveRecord.  I can see that the database log generates the SQL statements and I see the DB log file getting generated - however, I am not able to find the tables (.database only shows main and temp as databases).

**Ruby Connection Info**:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'sqlite3',
  :host => "localhost",
  :database => 'test1.db'
)
```

**Admin Model and ActiveRecord part**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'admins'
    create_table :admins do |table|
      table.column :email,     :string
      table.column :name, :string
    end
  end
end


class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :bills
end
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?  I do not think I have selected in-memory database in the case above.

Comment: Did you check the `db` directory and found nothing there?

Comment: the db file is not of 0 size - as I said before, when I type ".database", it shows main and temp but nowhere can I find my admins table

Comment: how are you creating tables, did you run the migrations or directly tried updating schema to check

Comment: trying to start RoR and most likely not that knowledgeable.  I created a  migration, ran rake db:migrate but for the bills model.  I simply ran the main ruby file in irb which contains the ActiveRecord Schema part for Admins - would that not create the table?

Comment: The title is a bit vague. Also OP mentions not using rails in another comment, yet the RoR tag. Consider editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you run `rake db:migrate` in your console before doing anything else. That should create the table. You will not see a separate file containing a table, where are all within `test1.db`. I recommend using the `.sqlite3` extension, so use `test1.sqlite3`.

Also, I recommend configuring your database with `config/database.yml`, rather than establishing connection manually with ActiveRecord.

That said, try firing up your `rails dbconsole` from your shell and running `.tables`

```
rails dbconsole
sqlite3>.tables
```

If you can't get that to work, use your `rails console`, and check out your model to see if they can hit the database:

```
rails c
Admin.create(email: "test@example.com", name: "Test from Console")
Admin.all
=> # Should return the test entry
```

That should let you interact with and read your tables. There is no separate file for each table.

Comment: forgot to mention I am not using rails - sinatra with activerecord